# Wordpress WP_Query compare not working?

Tags: wp-query

There are my arguments for my custom `WP_Query`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '9',
    'name'=>'Products',
    'compare'=>'LIKE'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $the_query->request;
```

which returns the following query:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND wp_posts.post_name = 'products' 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

As I can see, this is not creating a `LIKE` query like I'd like to have one.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The `compare` parameter can be used in meta/date queries? Check out the [WP_Query docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is a `LIKE` query. But you're using the `compare` arguments that are only present for `meta_query` arguments. You need to utilize a filter like the following:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse120358TitleLike', 10, 2 );
function wpse120358TitleLike( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if (
        'post' === $wp_query->get( 'post_type' )
        AND $wp_query->get( 'name' )
        // add further restriction arguments here:
        // AND ...
        )
    {
        $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
            ' AND %s LIKE %s',
            "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title",
            '%'.like_escape( $wp_query->get( 'name' ) ).'%'
        );
    }

    return $where;
}
```

Note that this is not a tested script. It's meant as a guideline that can be built upon.